# Word 2003 template with VBA macros that does not run properly in Word 2011 for MAC

Tags: macos, vba, ms-word

As the title says, I've got a word  template with macros that does not run properly in the new Word version from Office 2011 for MAC.

The thing which seems to not work properly is the following code:

```
Sub Document_New()
    myForm.Show
End Sub
```

The same is with Document_Open()

It doesn't seem to run this code on the Mac version.

Does anyone know why this won't work on the Mac, or if there's another way around to emulate the document_open/document_new function?

EDIT: The document is in the .dot format. And I tried to save it to .doc, then the Document_open() worked just fine, so it seems to not be working in the .dot format.. And Document_New() is not running in .doc since its not a new templatefile based on a document..

EDIT 2: Seems like it was a once only with the Document_open on .doc files. I cant make it work again. So weird! The only event I get working, and this is only when using the .doc file format, is Document_Close() - this works everytime...

EDIT 3: This is just getting weirder. I made a new .doc document with the following code:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
    MsgBox ("BlaBlaBla")
End Sub
```

The code only runs if the Visual Basic Editor is open BEFORE I close the word file and try to open it again. If I close the Visual Basic Editor and then the word file, and then open the word file; The code is not run.

??

Comment: Your last edit makes all sense. There can only be one VB-run process, and when the VB editor is launched, you are able to control execution (the play/pause Stop buttons). So, if you where getting problems running the _Open() event with active VB-editor, that's the cause. All application VB events are suppressed, as it would mean an unintended code execution.

Answer (score 1):

All VB application events are suppressed if you have the VB-editor active, and the current project is not running. It is an intentional behavior, to prevent unwanted code execution, hence not debuggable.

I have used Workbook_Open() (in Excel), and I can only see it working on newly open Excel Xls (xlsm on 2010), from a non-open VB-editor Excel application.
It will work if you have other doc/xls already open, but not if vb-editor is up.

Have you checked whether Macros are allowed? Do you have generated a certificate and setup your application as a trusted source?

Comment: Macros is allowed. And the events is available on the workbook object. This is so weird. Now I only get the Document_Close() to work. And this is only when using .doc file format.

Comment: I'm sorry that I mentioned the Workbook object... that's on Excel, not Word. Hmm... let me try some things to check why this might be happening, although from your edits it seams a well defined (intentional) behavior.

Comment: Thanks for taking time on testing! The behaviour differs from word 2003/2007 on PC. And I see no good reason on why it should need you to have the VB editor open before closing the document, in order to run these events..?

Comment: I agree that last bit is weird... it may have to do with the way they prevent code execution (marking something on the file...). Do you save the document from the word frontend or from the VB-editor?

Comment: I dont need to save it. The VB editor just have to be open when I CLOSE the document, in order to make the code run when the document is opened next time. No saving needed.

Comment: In case you were wondering how I saved the document the first time I saved it, then the answer is the word frontend :-)

Comment: In that case I smell a bug in brushed aluminum unibody casing... I have no such behavior in office 2010 word or excel for windows. You could do MAC-world some service by reporting this to MS... it will get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar issues. It seems that MS removed support for the Document_New and Document_Open functions in the Word object model for Word 2011. See http://mac2.microsoft.com/vb/1033/Word/html/womscChangesBetweenWord2010and2011.htm